# How to find the total number of SQL queries made by a django application?

Tags: django

Is there a way to find out how many SQL queries made by django app. when I try to load a page? What I like to do as I browse from page to page.. is to record the following in a text file... or see it in stdout.

1. page url
2. total queries
3. total query execution time

is there such tool/script?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [debug_toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) app, it prints not only number of queries, but each one of them and how long they took to run + a lot more useful info.

One thing to remember - this app makes django use quite a bit more memory, so it's best used only in the test environment.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118183/how-to-debug-in-django-the-good-way) is a related question with good answers.