# Django SelectDateWidget not saving date

Tags: django, django-registration

I am using the SelectDateWidget with django-registration to save a Birth Date at registration. I have tried excluding the birthday and the a profile is created and saved with the extra data. I am not quite sure where everything is going wrong.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    ...
    dob = models.DateField(_('birthday'))
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget

class ProfileRegistration(RegistrationFormTermsOfService):
    ...
    dob = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(1999,1939,-1)),
                          label=_("Birthday"),
                          )
```

prifilebackend.py

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from registration.models import RegistrationProfile

    ...
    class Backend(default.DefaultBackend):
        ...
        p = Profile.objects.get(user=new_user)
        p.dob=kwargs['dob']
        p.save()
```

The error I am getting when registering the user is: profile_profile.dob may not be NULL

The post data is generating dob_day, dob_month and dob_year. i have tried to clean the data but to no avail. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**Solved:**

profilebackend.py

```
signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                     user=new_user,
                                     request=request)

        u = User.objects.get(username=new_user.username)
        u.first_name = kwargs['first_name']
        u.last_name = kwargs['last_name']

        gender = kwargs['gender']
        dob = kwargs['dob']

        p = Profile(user = new_user, gender = gender, dob = dob)
        p.save()
        u.save()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [cleaned data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data) from the [bound form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms) instance should include the correct date object, if the form has no errors.

Use this date object to assign it to `p.dob`

I don't quite get how you process your registration form, but in general it works like this: After the form is submitted by the user, you create a bound form, make sure it is valid and then access the cleaned form data. Something like this:

```
# forms.py
...
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    dob = forms.DateField(widget=widgets.SelectDateWidget())

# views.py
...
def myform_view(request):
    ...
    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            dob = form.cleaned_data.get('dob')
            # dob is now a python date object
            do_something_with_birthday(dob)
```

If the `dob` date object is still `None` or empty when trying to save it using your backend,  I'd suggest you start debugging your code. You can install [django_extensions](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/) and run a development server with `./manage.py runserver_plus` to get a nice interactive stack trace of this exception. Alternatively, you can also debug your [code with pdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118183/how-to-debug-in-django-the-good-way).

Comment: I am using a custom backend and I have been able to save a first_name and last_name. the following: `def clean_dob(self):
  dob = self.cleaned_data.get('dob')
  print dob` in my forms.py is print the date in the correct format before the error occurs. Still so solution.

Comment: Please see the debugging notes at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice saving in the backend did the trick. See above for my solution. I was trying to avoid customizing the view. I didn't see any reason to.