# Django: Admin attempts to write User and returns a 404

Tags: python, django, authentication, admin

I have set up a standard django auth and admin in my project. I am running django 1.6.2 and python 2.7.4 with django-pyodbc-azure and an SQL Server 2008R2 backend

I am trying to add a new user from the Admin, I enter username and password, and then "Save", and I get redirected to /admin/auth/user/<< newid >>, and this brings up a 404.

Every time I set up the new user, the counter goes up by 1.

I am using the standard django management run server command, and I don't see any tracebacks. I've attempted to create the User from the shell, and that works fine. I've commented out all my apps in my settings.py, so there should be no conflicting models.

Does anyone have any idea where this problem could be?

Where do I even start debugging this, given I have no error message?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a debugger like ipdb and step through it.

See [How to debug in Django, the good way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118183/how-to-debug-in-django-the-good-way)

You could either start from the beginning, or look for some good breakpoint.

Are the new users stored in the DB, but just not visible in the admin?