# Unhandled exception in thread started by ... ValueError: the query contains a null character

Tags: python, django, sqlite

When I use `python manage.py runserver`,and get such tracebacks as following:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f518da18230>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/program/mtl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data/program/mtl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
self.check_migrations()
  File "/data/program/mtl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 437, in check_migrations
executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/data/program/mtl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/data/program/mtl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 52, in __init__
self.build_graph()
  File "/data/program/mtl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 203, in build_graph
self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/data/program/mtl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
self.ensure_schema()
  File "/data/program/mtl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in ensure_schema
with self.connection.schema_editor() as editor:
  File "/data/program/mtl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 27, in __enter__
return super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self).__enter__()
  File "/data/program/mtl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 86, in __enter__
self.atomic.__enter__()
  File "/data/program/mtl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 184, in __enter__
connection.set_autocommit(False, force_begin_transaction_with_broken_autocommit=True)
  File "/data/program/mtl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 389, in set_autocommit
self._start_transaction_under_autocommit()
  File "/data/program/mtl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 318, in _start_transaction_under_autocommit
self.cursor().execute("BEGIN")
  File "/data/program/mtl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/data/program/mtl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/data/program/mtl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 336, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
ValueError: the query contains a null character
```

what I use:
django 1.10
python2.7
virtualenv

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
```

I have searched for a long time. Does anyone can help me?or occured the same problem like mine?

Comment: I add "print repr(query) in base.py,line 336",and  got ************* "\n            SELECT name, type FROM sqlite_master\n            WHERE type in ('table', 'view') AND NOT name='sqlite_sequence'\n            ORDER BY name"
************* 'PRAGMA foreign_keys'
************* 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = 0'
************* u'BEGIN'

Comment: You should add your models and related views (if there is any), too. And can you query over your models in `python manage.py shell` ?

Comment: then I excute "sqlite3 db.sqlite3", and sqlite> select name,type from sqlite_master where type in ('table','view') and name='sqlite_sequence' order by name;
sqlite_sequence|table.

Comment: @alix I can't,and got the same error

Comment: You can run django under pdb to examine the value and its origins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug in Django, the good way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118183/how-to-debug-in-django-the-good-way)