# Django/Python Unit Testing: Let exceptions rise

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, debugging

I'm debugging a unit test failure whereby an exception is raised from the guts of some libraries; many exceptions. I'm using `ipdb` from the commandline to debug it.

when running `./manage.py test path.to.test` and the exception happens, the test runner catches the exception, prints a stack trace and marks the test failed or whatever. I get why this is useful, rather than letting the exception rise.

In my case, I want it to rise so `ipdb` catches it and lands me in a nice position to move up/down frames and debug the issues. I don't want to keep wrapping tests in `try` or putting `ipdb.set_trace()` calls where the exceptions are thrown. It is a pain and it is slowing down debugging. Ordinarily this isn't an issue, but today it is.

**Q:** Can I stop the test runner catching the exception so `ipdb` catches it instead without code modifications?

I feel like there should be a way to do this, as it would be very helpful when debugging, but I have missed it somewhere along the line.

(Ps, Python 2.7, Django 1.6 *sadface*)

Comment: Is using pytest as your runner an option? https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#dropping-to-pdb-python-debugger-on-failures It has a specific option for bubbling to pdb.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... would using Pycharm be an option for you? You might find it much easier just to use this to set breakpoints

Comment: @Sayse I am using charm, but for some reason (probably the huge size of the codebase) using charm's breakpoints and debugger is _stupidly_ slow to run the test. More time wasted, so I tend to just use ipdb.

Comment: @MattSeymour thanks for the hint, I will look at http://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118183/how-to-debug-in-django-the-good-way/6880214 related

Answer (score 1):

There exist [django-nose](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose), a django `unittest runner`, which still has support for django 1.6 and python 2.7.

There is an [`--pdb`](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/man.html#cmdoption-pdb) option for nose which:

> Drop into debugger on failures or errors

And you can run it as follows:

```
nosetests --pdb
```

Since you want to work with `ipdb`, there exist [this nose plugin](https://github.com/flavioamieiro/nose-ipdb) which allows `nose` to use `ipdb`:

```
nosetests --ipdb
```

Comment: Looks promising, I will check this out, thanks for the answer +1

Comment: Good luck :) @AidenBell

Comment: No luck, 1.6 (at least the version we have  ... vendored :( ) isn't compatible and working back through the django-nose versions yields no luck. Shame, might plug at it and try to find a workaround as a drop-in looks promising.