# objects.all() not working - django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

i have below model,

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class user_files(models.Model):
    Filename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Browse = models.FileField()
```

and in my view i want all data from above model,
my view is..

```
def user_in(request):

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'accounts/logout.html')

    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form_new = Fileupload(request.POST, request.FILES )
            #instance=form_new.save(commit=False)
            #instance.save()
            if form_new.is_valid():
                form_new.save()
                return redirect('in')
        else:
            form_new = Fileupload()
            data = user_files.objects.all()
            return render(request, 'accounts/in.html', {'form_new': form_new}, {'data':data})
```

and in my template i am writing,

```
<div>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        {% for da in data %}
            <h3>{{data.Filename}}</h3>
        {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}

</div>
```

but in my view, it is showing error for objects.all() as unresolved attribute.
i am stuck . i am using pycharm.
How to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You solve it by ignoring the irrelevant warning in Pycharm and running your code.

Comment: Also you want to pass one single dict to `render()`, not two distinct ones... but that's another issue.

Comment: how to ignore irrelevant warning in pycharm?

Comment: Warnings are not errors, so please run server and evaluate view response.

Comment: you  mean like this user.is_authenticated()  ?

Comment: Yes, in view function. In template it is ok.

Comment: @temasso It depends which version of Django the OP is running. In Django 1.10+, [`user.is_authenticated`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) is an attribute, and in Django 2.0 `user.is_authenticated()` will stop working.

Comment: @Alasdair You're right, it depends.

Comment: i ran server..  BUT IT IS NOT RETURNING ANY DATA

Comment: So try to debug your view. [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1118271/2839169)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering like this

```
<h3>{{data.Filename}}</h3>
```

'data' is a QuerySet it will not have any Filename attribute.

you have to do this.

```
<h3>{{da.Filename}}</h3>
```

Comment: i already imported required model in my view. and now also changed data.filename to da.filename. But still not showing data on template.    whereas i printed data on console, it is showing all objects there.                     my template,

{% for da in data %}
    <h3>{{da.Filename}}</h3>
{% endfor %}

in view , i have written,
   data = user_files.objects.all()
            #print(data)
            return render(request, 'accounts/in.html', {'form_new': form_new}, {'data':data})

i dont know what i am missing?

Comment: I think this line is unusual
`render(request, 'accounts/in.html', {'form_new': form_new}, {'data':data})` 
right one
`render(request, 'accounts/in.html', {'form_new': form_new,'data':data})`

The third positional argument should be the context as above line