# After adding django-debug to App, getting "'djdt' is not a registered namespace"

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

My question is about setting up to use django-debug.
I'm getting the above error after installing the toolbar and panel, and enabling these in my app. I've seen many suggestions for this or a closely related issue, and nothing I've tried has helped.

The specific error, during template rendering of /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debug_toolbar/templates/debug_toolbar/base.html, is from:

```
16       data-render-panel-url="{% url 'djdt:render_panel' %}"
```

My relevant settings.py entries:

```
DEBUG = True
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'debug_toolbar',
    'debug_panel',
    ...
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'debug_panel.middleware.DebugPanelMiddleware',
    ...
]
INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1',]
```

Appended to my urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    try:
        import debug_toolbar
        urlpatterns += [url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls))]
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

What I've tried:

- changing the order of these Middleware entries in settings.py (first, middle and last)
- adding a namespace attribute to my urlpatterns entry

Thanks for any further suggestions.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to manually add 'djdt' routes to the end of urls.py (if you use 'namespace' in your apps, add below codes to 'urls.py' in your project):

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar

    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ]
```

Comment: Be sure to add it to the *project* urls.py file, NOT your application urls.py.

Comment: It's slightly different now. See https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#setting-up-urlconf

Answer (score 10):

if this problem occurs when we set `DEBUG` to `False` then simply removing debugtoolbar middleware from the list fixed the problem.

- settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

if DEBUG is False:
    del MIDDLEWARE[0]
```

- urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include

...

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
```

Comment: This would be okay but it will be error if the first item of the MIDDLEWARE is not  of 'debug_toolbar'.

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure that you  put the following at the end of the project urls.py not the app urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar

    urlpatterns += [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ]
```

also make sure to add the following  in settings.py

```
if DEBUG:

    MIDDLEWARE += (
        'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    )
    INSTALLED_APPS += (
        'debug_toolbar',
    )
    INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)
    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
        'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
    }
```

Comment: That was my problem, I was using it in the wrong urls.py file! NICE!!

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to we declare its middle but the module is not import in case DEBUG = FALSE. So, just check to add its middle in case DEDEUG is set TRUE

settings.py

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
....
]

if DEBUG:
    
    MIDDLEWARE = ['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware'] + MIDDLEWARE
```

urls.py

```py
if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using both `debug_toolbar` and `debug_panel`
And in the [documentation](https://github.com/recamshak/django-debug-panel) for debug panel it is mentioned you need to remove `debug_toolbar`.

> Replace the Django Debug Toolbar middleware with the Django Debug
>   Panel one.

Replace:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

with:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'debug_panel.middleware.DebugPanelMiddleware',
    ...
)
```

I would recommend not using [django-debug-panel](https://github.com/recamshak/django-debug-panel) since it is not actively maintained. It was last modified 3 years back.

Comment: Thanks for response, but your recommended change did not work, I've been shuffling debug-toolbar/panel alternatives in/out for some time. If panel is not recommended (and presumably also toolbar), what is the alternative to debug models/views/etc in Django?

Comment: why don't you use pdb?

Comment: Yes, that seems like the best way to debug problems, per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118183/how-to-debug-in-django-the-good-way) stackoverflow question/answers. I'm particularly interested in the Visual Studio recommendation.

Comment: Unfortunately I have only worked with pycharm, so I'm unaware of visual studio

Comment: rather than see unwarranted down-votes on your answer, I'll uncheck it so that I can give correct answer to Milad (higher votes). I've moved on to Flask, so not in a position to check.

Answer (score 0):

I received this message because the documentation is mission the import statement in the urls.py file.

In urls.py add to the top of the file

```
import debug_toolbar
```