# How to debug web requests with Django and pdb?

Tags: python, django

I would like to use pdb to debug a view in Django but so far i've been unsuccessful, getting a BdbQuit error:

The view i've tried this on is a simple get request:

```
def get_file_names(request):
    pdb.set_trace()
    my_files = Files.objects.filter(user_id=request.user))
    name_list += list(map(lambda x: (x.id, x.name, x.description),
                          my_files))

    return JsonResponse({'rows': name_list})
```

**A couple notes:**

- I prefer not to use Django pdb since this forces me to modify the    client's request parameters.
- I also do not want to call my code from pdb (since this code is being
  called from the client).
- Django Version 1.10.6
- The app is running inside a docker container

Does anyone have a solution which works? Im finding that debugging complex web requests in python can be very tedious and it would be really amazing if pdb worked.

Note this is not a subprocess, just a simple get request (eventually i would like it to work on a more complex request but i've posted a simple example since this already fails).

Any suggestions? Suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118183/how-to-debug-in-django-the-good-way) dont seem to work.

Comment: Why dont you use an IDE like VSCode for debugging django?

Comment: instead of `pdb` you can use `ipdb`, which is uses iPython hence gives better control, along with stuff like autocomplete.

Comment: [wdb](https://github.com/Kozea/wdb) has worked for me, as has the [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) IDE.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run `pdb` inside a Django app running inside a container, you must run with the `-it` flags.

`docker run -it .... djangoimage`

If you're running detached (`-d`), you can attach to your container `docker attach $IDCONTAINER`.

If you're running with docker-compose:

```
services:
  django:
    # ...
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

And then use the `docker attach` to attach to the Django container when you run the `pdb`.

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir