# Django view doesn't properly redirect

Tags: python-3.x, django

When view function - index is called with post request it doesn't redirect. Print inside the function executes. Can't find reason. I changed return redirect('/result') to return HttpResponse("some text") and it does not work either. I use Django 1.9.5.

My code:

```
data = {"number" : 0}

@csrf_exempt
def result(request):
    global data
    response = "solution: " + str(data['number'])
    return HttpResponse(response)

@csrf_exempt 
def index(request):         
    global data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploadFile1 = request.FILES['file1']
        uploadFile2 = request.FILES['file2']
        text1 = ''
        text2 = ''
        with open('file1', 'wb+') as file1:     
            text1 = uploadFile1.read()
        with open('file1', 'wb+') as file2:
            text2 = uploadFile2.read()
        data = calcpy.views.getNumber(str(text1), str(text2))
        print('test') #this executes
        return redirect("/result")
    
    template = loader.get_template('main.html')
    context = {'solution' : 0}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

My urls.py code:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from . import views
import version.models

web_srv_prefix = version.models.getWebSrvPrefix()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^' + web_srv_prefix + '/ajax/(?P<module>\w+)/(?P<function>\w+)/', views.ajax, name='ajax'),
                       url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
               url(r'^result/$', views.result, name='result')
        
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`redirect` accepts a url **name** not a **path**, use this:

```
return redirect('result')
```

Comment: You're right, but it still doesn't work, even if I change return redirect('resutl') to return HttpResponse("some text"). It basically does not execute.

Comment: Only with prints, and breakpoint() function. Not found anything useful.

Comment: try debugging using your IDE, if youre using PyCharm heres a guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118183/how-to-debug-in-django-the-good-way