# Unable to run vscode's debugger with dockerized django project

Tags: python, django, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Every time when I run a debugger there happen many things but not what I expect.

I'm running a project with `docker-compose up`

Checking the localhost if backend backend is okay. It's down.
What's funny the container is running because I'm attached to this with vscode's remote containers.

The `debugpy` library is installed.

The first approach to run a debugger end with such info in debug console:

```
Attached!
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
workflow.State.additional_values: (fields.W904) django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField is deprecated. Support for it (except in historical migrations) will be removed in Django 4.0.
    HINT: Use django.db.models.JSONField instead.
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: accounts, auth, contenttypes, files, mambu, otp_totp, sessions, token_blacklist, workflow, zoho
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

and it's down. Backend is also down.

Second try:

```
Attached!
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
workflow.State.additional_values: (fields.W904) django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField is deprecated. Support for it (except in historical migrations) will be removed in Django 4.0.
    HINT: Use django.db.models.JSONField instead.
Zoho Configuration failed, check that you have all variables ZOHO_TOKEN_URL, ZOHO_REST_API_KEY, ZOHO_CURRENT_USER_EMAIL
```

and it's down but backend is up - I'm able to login etc.

The third try ends with such an error `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5678`.

Any tips?

Code:

manage.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys

def initialize_debugger():
    import debugpy

    debugpy.listen(("0.0.0.0", 5678))
    debugpy.wait_for_client()
    print('Attached!')

def main():
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "xxx.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    initialize_debugger()
    main()
```

The local docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.2"

services:
  backend:
    container_name: xxx
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: ../build/backend.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/opt/app
    command: ./run.sh
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "5678:5678"
    env_file:
      - build/.env-local
    links:
      - db:db
      - rabbit:rabbit
      - memcached:memcached
  celery:
    container_name: xxx
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: ../build/backend.Dockerfile
      context: ./backend
    command: ./run_celery.sh
    env_file:
      - build/.env-local
    working_dir: /opt/app/
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/opt/app
    links:
      - db:db
      - rabbit:rabbit
  frontend:
    container_name: xxx
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: ../build/frontend.Dockerfile
    environment:
      - BROWSER=none
      - CI=true
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/src/:/frontend/src
      - ./frontend/public/:/frontend/public
  nginx:
    container_name: xxx
    build:
      dockerfile: build/nginx.Dockerfile
      context: .
      args:
        REACT_APP_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TOKEN: $REACT_APP_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TOKEN
        REACT_APP_PAGESENSE_LINK: $REACT_APP_PAGESENSE_LINK
        REACT_APP_CHATBOT_TOKEN: $REACT_APP_CHATBOT_TOKEN
        REACT_APP_SENTRY_DSN: $REACT_APP_SENTRY_DSN
        REACT_APP_SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT: $REACT_APP_SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT
        REACT_APP_SENTRY_TRACES_SAMPLE_RATE: $REACT_APP_SENTRY_TRACES_SAMPLE_RATE
        REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_API_URL: $REACT_APP_THIRD_PARTY_API_URL
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
    env_file:
      - build/.env-local
    volumes:
      - ./build/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx.conf
  db:
    container_name: xxx
    image: postgres:12
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
  rabbit:
    container_name: xxx
    image: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
  memcached:
    container_name: xxx
    image: memcached
    ports:
      - "11211:11211"
    restart: always
  flower:
    image: mher/flower:0.9.5
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://xxx-rabbitmq//
      - FLOWER_PORT=8888
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
```

and the launch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "CF: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5678
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/backend",
                    "remoteRoot": "/opt/app/"
                }
            ],
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does it start without including the debugpy?

Comment: @pygeek yes, it does.

Answer (score 3):

There could be many reasons why debugging does not work as intended. Troubleshooting is usually the reasonable thing to do. Starting from something simple and adding complexity until figuring out what step is not working as intended. I would recommend starting with a simple debugging session using `pdb`, before adding VS Code complexity. In order to accomplish that, you just need to add a `breakpoint()` in your backend code where you want to debug. In your `docker-compose.yaml`, you want to add to your `backend` service, the following additional configurations

```yaml
services:
  backend:
    - tty: true
    - stdin_open: true
```

In your terminal, start your application with `docker-compose up`. Open a second terminal and attach to your container with `docker attach <project name>_backend`. You should normally get a prompt `pdb>` at the location where your `breakpoint` was hit.

Based on your description, here are the points I would investigate.

### debugpy installation

Make sure debugpy is installed in the Docker image and not locally.

### WSGI HTTP server

I presume you're using `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` to start the WSGI HTTP server. Just in case you're using something like gunicorn, it's worth mentioning that you should only use 1 worker. As an example, if using gunicorn, you can provide the amount of workers at the command line: `gunicorn --workers=1 --timeout=1200 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 your_application.wsgi:application`.

Note also the huge timeout. You might want to set a high value both for your WSGI HTTP server and for Nginx. If one of them times out while you're debugging, you will get a 502 or 504 error depending on which one timed out first and your debugging session will terminate.

### debugpy location

I usually place the code importing `debugpy` in `wsgi.py`, right before the call to `get_wsgi_application()`

```py
"""
WSGI config for {{ project_name }} project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/{{ docs_version }}/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', '{{ project_name }}.settings')

import debugpy
debugpy.listen(('0.0.0.0', 5678))
debugpy.wait_for_client()
print('Attached!')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 2):

Django don't support debugging by its own

this is what I fount of surfing in  2 min

[this might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118183/how-to-debug-in-django-the-good-way)